# DataGridView: Using CellParsing to get Nullable<TimeSpan>

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing, datagridview, timespan

I'm trying to implement a custom parsing for a DataGridView. It's supposed to convert the entered value to a TimeSpan? (Nullable<TimeSpan>).

My code is as follows:

```
private void dataGridViewWeek_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
{
    if((e.Value is string) && (e.DesiredType == typeof(TimeSpan?)))
    {
        string lsValue = ((string)e.Value).Trim();

        if(!lsValue.IsTimeSpan()) e.Value = null;
        else e.Value = lsValue.ToTimeSpan();

        e.ParsingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

**IsTimeSpan** is an extension method which returns **true** if the supplied string can be converted to a **TimeSpan**.

**ToTimeSpan** is another extension which performs my custom parsing.

So far, so good, the parsing works perfectly for entered numbers.

The problem is with entering invalid characters (' ' (single whitespace), 'x', ...), which sets **e.Value** to **null**. Then I always get a DataGridView error popup.

If I enter nothing (type something and delete it all and then leave the cell), it doesn't display said error.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Changing the `e.Value = null;` to `e.Value = new TimeSpan?();` didn't help, either.

Comment: If it's failing your custom `IsTimeSpan` check, then you'll have to show us that code.  Is there a reason you can't just use `TimeSpan.TryParse` or `TimeSpan.TryParseExact` instead?

Comment: @Matt Johnson It's not failing on `IsTimeSpan`, that method works exactly as expected, double- nay, triple-checked that. I'm not using `TimeSpan.TryParse` or `TimeSpan.TryParseExact` because I want to do custom parsing for the entered values.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?